# Regex for third occurence of <ul>

Tags: php, regex

Using php and Regex I am attempting to add `<li>Valid in US</li>` in the last `UL` after the last `LI` or to simply put after the last `LI`.

When debugging I cannot even get the contents of the last `UL` tag. This code brings up nothing when I do a var_dump (I have also tried `preg_match_all` with it):

```
if (preg_match("/((<ul>(.*?)<\/ul>/s){3})", $desc, $WARRANTY) == true)
var_dump($WARRANTY);
```

This is contents of `$desc`:

```
<h1>Stuff</h1>
<p>description</p>
<hr />
<strong>Features &amp; Benefits</strong>
<ul>
  <li>feat</li>
  <li>feat</li>
  <li>feat</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<strong>Specifications</strong>
<ul>
  <li>spec</li>
  <li>spec</li>
  <li>spec</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<strong>Warranty Information for a certain product</strong>
<ul>
  <li>3 Years Parts</li>
  <li>3 Years Labor</li>
</ul>
<div> <a href="/ahref" target="_blank">See more products from MFG </a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the `<ul>` tag with only 2 `<li>` tags in it, you can use this regex:

```
<ul>\s*(<li>[^<]+</li>\s*){2}</ul>
```

I can suggest another hacky way of adding the third li tag:

- use this regex:

  `<ul>\s*(?:<li>[^<]+</li>\s*){2}(<)/ul>`
- and replace the match in the first group with your `<li></li>` content followed by a `<` - because that's what has been captured by the group `(<)`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use regex, and is very hacky, but works.

```
if($pos = strripos($desc, '</ul>')) {
    $desc= substr_replace($desc, "<li>Valid in US</li>\n</ul>" , $pos, strlen($desc));
}

echo $desc;
```